# Сохранение blob на Google Drive

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Столкнулся с проблемой при сохранении текстового файла на гугл диск 
Есть кнопка

```
    <div class="g-savetodrive"
        data-src={this.saveGoogleDrive()}
        data-filename="rawText.txt"
        data-sitename="App">
    </div>
```

есть метод

```
saveGoogleDrive() {
    const blob = new Blob(["Hello world!"], {type : "text/plain"});
    const uri = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    return uri;
}
```

проблема в том что гугл не хочет сохранять blob. Посоветуйте другие варианты сохранения текста ?

Comment: Вы SDK используете?

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach подгружаю `https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js`  через `load-script`